# Вызов стандартного приложения установки обоев

Tags: android, android-intent

Cоздаю программу для установки обоев на телефон, прошу подсказать как вызвать стандартное приложение телефона для установки обоев (которое обычно вызывается из галереи)? То есть, пользователь должен выбрать картинку в программе и нажать кнопку установки обоев, после чего должна передаться выбранная картинка и запуститься стандартное приложение для установки обоев.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Нужно получить `uri` файла с картинкой и передать его в `Intent`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
intent.putExtra("mimeType", "image/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Set as:"));
```